# How can I uninstall/reinstall Ubuntu from a dual boot with Windows 8.1?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

Right now I have a dual boot set up with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. However, I did some things on Ubuntu that caused some of the packages to become "inconsistent", and I tried to fix them but it didn't really work. Rather than try, probably in vain, to fix it, I thought I would just uninstall it, repartition everything and go through the whole installation again, and be more careful not to cause the same errors.

But if I simply erase the partitions, I won't be able to boot Windows, and unfortunately I don't have any sort of recovery disk/drive, I searched for hours and I've come to the conclusion that I will have to have Microsoft mail me a recovery disk, it's simply not available online. I do have the recovery partition, however. But the problem is that Windows doesn't seem to be recognizing it as such. If I try to use the wizard to create a recovery drive it tells me there is no recovery partition and that it doesn't have all the required files. In MiniTool Partition Wizard, it is clearly labeled "Recovery", and I checked the contents and it has everything it is supposed to have. But Windows doesn't think it exists, at least not as a recovery partition. In the Windows disk manager it is labeled as "Healthy (OEM Partition)". Maybe that is what it is supposed to be, but regardless it doesn't let me create any recovery media.

So how can I do this? I want to keep Windows just the way it is as far as my files and programs, but basically unpartition the drive and allow Windows to be the only operating system again, as if I never had Ubuntu on there in the first place. I may reinstall Ubuntu afterwards, or try doing it a different way, or try a different Linux OS altogether. But I can't do this unless I restore the partitions and the Windows boot configuration.

I have an idea but I'm not sure it will work, so I wanted to get some opinions from people who have more experience. If I were to manually copy the recovery partition to an external drive, could I then make it bootable, boot into it without even touching the partitions myself, and use the recovery disk to do all the repartitioning and restoration of Windows configuration by itself, without losing my Windows files, programs and setup? That would be ideal, because if I got stuck not able to boot into Windows it would be a huge problem, especially if the Ubuntu partitions were totally gone. Then I wouldn't even be able to reinstall it and regain the Ubuntu boot configuration, unless I formatted my Windows partition. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ubuntu installation disk to do that. You can use the "Try Ubuntu" option on the Live CD to back up your files and if you use the "Install Ubuntu" it  will recognize your windows and Linux partition and you will have the option to resize and format your partitions.